# JSON cortado ao enviar por post com AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

estou usando o Angular para fazer um cadastro no banco de dados, eu pego os dados dos meus inputs coloco em um objeto e transformo em um JSON e mando por post, mas acontece que o meu JSON é cortado e não faço a minima idéia de o por que.

```
 var meuJson = angular.toJson(meuObjeto);
 $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'http://url/arquivo.php',
   data: {
     'data': meuJson
   }
 })
 .success(function (data){
    console.log(data);
  })
```

Meu JSON está aparecendo assim.

```
[
  {
    "uuid":"56456456456456456456465456"
  },
  {
    "store_name":"",
    "store_email":"",
    "store_facebook":"",
    "contact_name":"Juca",
    "contact_email":"email@gmail.com",
    "contact_facebook":"http://localho
```

Eu dei um `console.log()` com o Json quando eu pego ele e mostro, depois eu mostro a resposta, vejam a imagem que fica melhor de entender:

[image: Clique aqui para ver a imagem]

Comment: Ele está cortando antes de enviar ou no arquivo.php?

Comment: Você armazena o JSON no banco de dados e recupera ele? Ou você converte uma consulta no banco em um JSON?

Comment: @AlessandroGomes quando eu dou o console.log na minha máquina antes do envio ele está correto. Então no `arquivo.php` eu dou um `var_dump($_POST)` e aparece já cortado.

Comment: @DiegoLopesLima eu salvo ele no local storage recupero e envio.

Comment: Poderi tentar dar mais detalhes por favor?

Comment: @DiegoLopesLima, um json é enviado via POST, para um arquivo.php, esse arquivo php não faz nada além de dar um `var_dump($_POST)` (estamos debugando), aparece a string que está sendo enviada, só que cortada, do jeito que descrevi na pergunta.

Comment: Você está usando algum CMS, framework ou template engine? (Wordpress por exemplo)

Comment: @DiegoLopesLima, não, php puro.

Comment: Já tentou com jQuery?

Comment: Tem como postar o respectivo trecho do PHP que recebe?

Comment: @Khronna, pode colocar o JSON todo, __ou pelo menos__ a linha a seguir à parte onde é cortado? tenho uma suspeita.

Comment: @Sergio estou participando desse projeto também, então coloquei uma imagem do console com o array inteiro e depois como ele volta.

Comment: Acompanha no Fiddler2 e veja como que está se comportando a requisição e a resposta

Answer (score 2):

Ainda não tenho permissões para fazer comentários, então postarei uma alternativa mesmo assim: bem, eu já tive problemas similares com transferências cortadas, e um dos principais problemas nesse caso é a codificação dos caracteres. Por algum motivo que desconheço, quando a codificação do texto enviada é diferente da codificação esperada pelo servidor em determinados casos ele corta a string a partir de um caractere que ele não pode interpretar - eu acho.

Para verificar a codificação do texto que está sendo enviado utilize o método [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-detect-encoding.php). Se a codificação do JSON recebida for diferente da esperada tente forçar a conversão pelo PHP, ou então definindo o charset da página que está enviando JSON.

Convertendo com o PHP:

```
$charset = mb_detect_encoding($_POST['data']);
$json = mb_convert_encoding($_POST['data'], "UTF-8", $encoding);
```

Convertendo com o HTML: http://www.w3c.br/cursos/html5/conteudo/capitulo3.html